# How to redirect user after red link click in Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

Is there any way to make Mediawiki redirect user on some specific page after clicking 'red link'?

It is supposed to use Semantic Forms to create pages in my project, so clicking red link should just send user to some predefined page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all pages to use the same form, then you can set the default form on a [per namespace basis](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSemantic_Forms/The_%22edit_with_form%22_tab#Based_on_namespace), by adding a page in the project namespace, with the name of the namespace, if that makes sense. In other words, if you want every new page in the namespace Car to be created using the `Form:Vehicle`, you should create the page `Project:Car`, and add the special property 'Has default form' there (eg by adding the text `[[Has default form::Car]]`). For the main namespace, `Project:Main` (or the localized name of your main namespace, as seen at `MediaWiki:Blanknamespace`) used to work. In later versions of MediaWiki this message is removed, so I am not entirely sure that works any more. This approach can be combined with per category or per page default forms.

If the link is a property, eg `[[drives car::Volvo]]`, you can add `[[Has default form::Vehicle]]` to the property page (Property:Drives car), to have all such red links use that form.